# Comparison of characters in python

Tags: python

I am a noob in programming, I am working with python on codeacademy and I came across this code which wanted to change the 'a's and 'A's present in phrase by 'X's

```
phrase = "A bird in the hand..."

for char in phrase:

    if char == "A" or char == "a":
        print "X",
```

this code worked fine for me but when i tried to change the if statement to this:

```
if char == ("A" or "a"):
```

only the A in the phrase changed into X
and when i altered the if statement to

```
if char == ("A" and "a"):
```

only the a in the phrase changed into X.

I went to my terminal and tried a few combinations of or and and comparisons between characters and obtained these results

```
>>> "a" or "A"
'a'
>>> "A" or "a"
'A'
>>> "A" and "a"
'a'
>>> "a" and "A"
'A'
>>> 2 or "a"
2
>>> 2 and "a"
'a'
>>> "a" and "b"
'b'
>>> "A" or 2
'A'
```

What I can interpret from this is that the 'or' is returning the first element while the 'and' is returning the second element but I am not sure why this is happening, can someone please throw some light on this. I was unable to search about this as I didn't know what exactly to search for, for this.

Comment: I like your thinking and it is a neat idea to be able to write constraints the way you did.  Logic programming takes full advantage of sets and closures to let you do things like that, but in regular-old imperative programming one must eschew uncertainty and learn the dumb, literal-minded ways of the compiler. EDIT: but, your concept does translate more literally into python as: if c in ['a', 'A']  (the 'if' gets mapped across each term of the list appearing after the 'in' keyword). P.S. You may also do something like: if c.lower() == 'a' (kill two birds with one stone)

Comment: I was also thinking of capitalizing the phrase for the if condition but then i thought that it wasn't the purpose of the exercise, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: There is not **distributive property**.  `("A" or "a")` is evaluated first. You need to write  `char == "A" or char =="a"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used in this context, `or` and `and` will return the last value evaluated. `or` requires one of the elements to be true. When you check `"A"  or "a"`, "A" evaluates to true immediately, so the evaluation ends,  and "A"  is returned. When you check `"A" and "a"`, "A" evaluates to true immediately, but "a" is also required by `and`, so it is then checked as well, and "a" is returned.

This behavior is not very legible. It's mainly useful when checking for None or empty containers.

As an aside for those interested, in Python and many other languages, this `and` and `or` logic is a special adoption of what's called "normal order" in a paradigm that otherwise follows "applicative order" evaluation. Check out super awesome SICP: 
https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node85.html

In general, you should either join straight forward boolean expressions with `or` -- `1 > 2 or "a" in "abc"`, or, better yet, use set containment: `if char in {"A",  "a"}`.

Comment: I'd mark `and` and `or` and `a` (and `A`) as code where appropriate. Would make your answer easier to read. And the "or -- == or == - -, or"  is a complete puzzle to me.

Comment: You're of course right, @StefanPochmann. I'm on my phone and was feeling lazy, but I've made the edits for you.

Comment: Thanks. With that, and after more thinking, I even understand the puzzle (that  `==` stands for an expression).

Answer (score 1):

You want to write `char == "A" or char == "a"`.

Comment: when i write
 char == "A" or char == "a", it works but why does it not work for
 char == ( "A" or "a") ?

Comment: Because `("A" or "a")` evaluates first; it's a boolean expression that resolves to true. Then `char == true` is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

```
char == ( "A" or "a")
```

Evaluates to:

```
char == (True or True)
```

Because strings are `truthy` in Python if they are not empty. Comparison `char == True` obviously yields `False`.

What you want is `in` operator

```
char in {"A", "a"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The others are right, but I'd just do `char in "Aa"`. Sets might be better if you have many options and you're concerned about speed, but here they're overkill.